# How i can print report without first column of table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to print some reports in my project my problem is printing report format you can get some idea from links. Now i print div but I want to print first column hide while printing

[this is now i print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTdni.png) 
[image]
 [I want this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDUoS.png)[image]

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                            function printDiv(divID)
                             {
                                //Get the HTML of div
                                var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
                                //Get the HTML of whole page
                                var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

                                //Reset the page's HTML with div's HTML only
                                document.body.innerHTML = 
                                "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + 
                                divElements + "</body>";

                                //Print Page
                                window.print();

                                //Restore orignal HTML
                                document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;

                            }
                     </script>
```

Comment: I am sorry william its column

Answer (score 1):

See css [media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html). You can define css rules that will be applied while printing, ex:

```
@media print {
    tr.firstRow {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@media print {
 table tr:first-child{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('table tr:first').hide();
```

before

```
//Print Page
window.print();
```

To `Hide` all `first columns` try,

```
$('table tr td:eq(0)').hide();
```

Comment: hiii @Rohan Kumar this is only hide 1st tr

Comment: @NavjotSingh try my answer now I've changed it.

Comment: @NavjotSingh then add an `id` to your `outermost table` and use that `id` like `$('table#tblId > tr > td:eq(0)').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

By using the media query in css:

```
@media print{
    /* and here everything you want print only */
    table tr:first-child{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

*Bare in mind: `first-child` doesnt always work, its an example. You could give it a class and use that*
This doesnt work very well in IE8 and lower, not sure about IE9. You can also do this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print_only.css media="print" />
```

You place that in the `head` of your page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                        function printDiv(divID)
                         {
                            //Get the HTML of div
                            var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
                            //Get the HTML of whole page
                            var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

                            //Reset the page's HTML with div's HTML only
                            document.body.innerHTML = 
                            "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + 
                            divElements + "</body>";

                            //Print Page
                            window.print();

                            //Restore orignal HTML
                            document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;

                        }
                 </script>
                 <div id="dd">shafi</div>
                 <div onClick="printDiv('dd');">print</div>
```